# What is the free radical mechanism of Ruff's degradation?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, radicals

There are very few resources on the mechanism of Ruff's degradation of carbohydrates, which adds $\ce{Br2}$ to oxidize aldehydic group of reducing sugars like glucose to carboxylic acid and then adds ferric ions $\ce{(Fe^3+)}$ with hydrogen peroxide $\ce{(H2O2)}$. Most sites simply show a concerted mechanism involving salt of $\ce{Fe^2+}$ and the sugar, however this isn't the proposed mechanism I'm searching for.

I want to know the free radical mechanism of Ruff's degradation involving OH free radicals. The mechanism should probably be similar to Fenton's reagent which uses ferrous $\ce{(Fe^2+)}$ ions with $\ce{H2O2}$.

Comment: If very few resources then you should refer to them for other not to duplicate your prior effort.

Comment: Please quote (if allowed) and **cite** resources for the concerted mechanism. Why do you believe it needs to be a different mechanism?

Answer (score 1):

Oxidation to the aldonic acid with bromine and water is an ionic redox mechanism.

Then due to the basic conditions from the counter anion of the iron3 salt, the carboxylic acid is deprotonated.

The Iron 3 can then oxidise the carboxylate oxygen to a radical, enabling the decarboxylation via free radical mechanism to leave a tertiary carbon radical.

As the peroxide O-O bond is weak it spontaneously undergoes homolytic cleavage and so the OH radical can  hence terminate with the carbon radical to produce the alditol.

Chemoselectively, the hydrogen peroxide will oxidise the C1 alcohol to produce the corresponding aldose.